# Intellij connect to docker postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, docker, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to connect to a Docker PostgreSQL database from IntelliJ.

I created a folder to mount and then a Postgres container

```
docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 --network=db -v "PWD:/var/lib/postgresql/data" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*** -d postgres:alpine
```

I am able to connect to docker psql via:

```
docker run -it --rm --network=db postgres:alpine psql -h db -U postgres
```

I have already created the database and can see it with the \l command. So it should exist?

```
                                      List of databases
        Name         |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
---------------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 mbraun              | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres            | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 student_application | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0           | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                     |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1           | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                     |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

But upon building IntelliJ tells me the database does not exist.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "student_application" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2665) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:147) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at mbraun.student_application.StudentApplicationKt.main(StudentApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
```

I do not know where to go from here or where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had postgres desktop up and running so all I had to do was change the port to something not 5432

Answer (score 3):

When you ran your container, you did not bind it to a host port. So when you write `localhost` as a db host, it is refering to your host, not your container.

You should run your container with the option `-p 5432:5432` for that to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made a mistake and forgot to include that before the above mentioned command I inserted: ```docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 --network=db \                                    
-v "$PWD:/var/lib/postgresql/data" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*** \
-d postgres:alpine``` This shouldm take care of the port right? But it is still not working

Comment: This should take care of the port yeah... How are you initializing your db ?

Comment: Sorry I am not quite sure what you mean. I am more or less following along a tutorial since this is my first time trying this. I pulled postgres:alpine then ran ```docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 --network=db \                                     -v "$PWD:/var/lib/postgresql/data" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*** \ -d postgres:alpine``` then ```docker run -it --rm --network=db postgres:alpine psql -h db -U postgres``` then created my database and after that tried to run my application in IntellliJ

Comment: When you say that you build it in IntelliJ, do you use docker in IntelliJ or do you build an app connecting to your localhost ? What I mean is, do you re-launch the container in IntelliJ ? I guess not ...